# How to access nested REST API with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, api, nested, restangular

I want to access to this api `password/reset/{token}` with Restangular. I try with this code but error me this function doesn't exist.

```
Restangular.one('password').one('reset',user.token).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
     console.log(response);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var token = user.token;
Restangular.one('password/reset/'+token).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
     console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: error me: Restangular.one(...).then is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Play around with these

```js
Restangular.one('password').customPOST("reset",user.token).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
     console.log(response);
})
```

or

```js
Restangular.one('password',"reset").post(user.token).then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
}, function(response) {
     console.log(response);
})
```